# Relative Path for React-Native-ffmpeg?

Tags: typescript, react-native, ffmpeg

I'm using react-native-ffmpeg and I'm trying to add some text and an image to my videos. I'm trying to get use a font file through a relative path, but I'm having some issues. Everything is executing correctly, but my video is saved using some default font instead of the font I want it to use.

This is the code I'm trying, these two lines to set the fontDirectory/path,

```
    await FFmpegKitConfig.setFontDirectory("../fonts");
    const fontFilePath = "../fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf";
```

then the command that I execute.
`-y -i ${inputFilePath} -i ${randomImage} -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=${imgWidthScale * windowWidth}:${imgHeightScale * windowHeight}, drawtext=fontfile=${fontFilePath}:text=@${selfUser.username}:fontsize=${fontSize}:fontcolor=white:x=${textWidthScale * windowWidth}:y=${textHeightScale * windowHeight}" -codec:a copy ${outputPath}`

I'm sure my font file is insde the fonts directory and that this path is correct. However, this is the error I'm getting in my terminal:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2877c2fa0] Error initializing filter 'drawtext'
 LOG  [AVFilterGraph @ 0x2877c2fa0]  with args 'fontfile=../fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf:text=@chris:fontsize=36:fontcolor=white...
```

Which I'm not too sure about, but looks like the colon delimiter is not working? However it seems to be reading all my other arguments fine as my text, fontsize, color, and position work with no issues.

Is there something I'm doing wrong in my command? Or setting up my font directory? Or does ffmpeg not work with relative paths? I appreciate any help :)